# Android: Long press of button to save sound (Soundboard)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have put together a basic soundboard using Android Studio. Please be warned; I am new to Android app development.

I have a series of buttons that I have managed to get to play some .mp3 sounds that I have placed in the Raw folder and mentioned in my MainActivity.java file.

Albeit, I would like the ability to be able to long press on the buttons to save the associated sound to the storage of the phone.

Does anybody have any idea how I could go about this please?

Many thanks, Billy.

````
import android.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mysound1;
    MediaPlayer mysound2;
    MediaPlayer mysound3;
    MediaPlayer mysound4;
    MediaPlayer mysound5;
    MediaPlayer mysound6;
    MediaPlayer mysound7;
    MediaPlayer mysound8;
    MediaPlayer mysound9;
    MediaPlayer mysound10;
    MediaPlayer mysound11;
    MediaPlayer mysound12;
    MediaPlayer mysound13;
    MediaPlayer mysound14;
    MediaPlayer mysound15;
    MediaPlayer mysound16;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mysound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nickingbentcoppers);
        mysound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bentcoppers);
        mysound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bentcoppers2);
        mysound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bentcoppers3);
        mysound5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.twentyfirstcentury);
        mysound6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.imdoingmine);
        mysound7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.illgoafterhim);
        mysound8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.iamcalm);
        mysound9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.likethebattle);
        mysound10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thatsright);
        mysound11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.seenenough);
        mysound12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jesusmary);
        mysound13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.changepage);
        mysound14 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.opendialog);
        mysound15 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yes);
        mysound16 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.no);

    }

    public void sound1(View view) {
        mysound1.start();
    }

    public void sound2(View view) {
        mysound2.start();
    }

    public void sound3(View view) {
        mysound3.start();
    }

    public void sound4(View view) {
        mysound4.start();
    }

    public void sound5(View view) {
        mysound5.start();
    }

    public void sound6(View view) {
        mysound6.start();
    }

    public void sound7(View view) {
        mysound7.start();
    }

    public void sound8(View view) {
        mysound8.start();
    }

    public void sound9(View view) {
        mysound9.start();
    }

    public void sound10(View view) {
        mysound10.start();
    }

    public void sound11(View view) {
        mysound11.start();
    }

    public void sound12(View view) {
        mysound12.start();
    }

    public void sound13(View view) {
        mysound13.start();
    }

    public void sound14(View view) {
        mysound14.start();
    }

    public void sound15(View view) {
        mysound15.start();
    }

    public void sound16(View view) {
        mysound16.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        mysound14.start();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit, feller?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        mysound15.start();

                        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(MainActivity.this);

                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        mysound16.start();
                    }
                })

                .show();

    }

    public void gotopage1(View v) {

        mysound13.start();
        finish();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }

    public void gotopage2(View v) {

        mysound13.start();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }

}```
````

Comment: My MainActivity.Java file code is pasted above, in case it is needed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't see where is your button but let's suppose button_one will save `mySound1` after long click

```
button_one.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {

     copyRAWtoPhone(R.raw.nickingbentcoppers,storagePath);

     return true;
 }
});
```

and here is `copyRawToPhone` function ,where first Variable id will be your raw file id and String path will be your phone storage path.

```
private void CopyRAWtoPhone(int id, String path) throws IOException {
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
try { 
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
        out.write(buff, 0, read);
    } 
} finally { 
    in.close();
    out.close();
 } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer. I have been looking at implementing it into my code now. The buttons themselves are only ever referenced in the activity_mail.xml file, where they are denoted by android:id="@+id/button6" etc for instance. I don't know if that makes a difference or not?

Comment: i didnt understand you exactly , please could you explain your question

Comment: Sorry, I mean that none of the buttons are mentioned in the Main Activity.java file at all. So I don't know if I have to add some extra code into Main.Activity as a result? I hope that makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: yes you have to add a widget(button , image, ...) that trigger the function copyRAWtophone once you click on it

Comment: Hi. My phone has a Download folder on the internal memory, as it does not have an external SD Card. What is the best way to set the save folder as the Download folder? Thanks.

Comment: File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); String path = dir.getAbsolutePath(); .
and dont forget to ask for permission

Comment: Thank you. I have added the line above and Android Studio has changed it to 'final File dir = .... ' , but there are no errors. I noticed on the above answer too that you have referred to this location as 'path' all the way through copyRAWtophone function. Does this stay the same, or should I change any references of 'path' to 'File dir' or just 'dir'? I hope that question makes sense!

Comment: Also, when you say ask for permission, is this just the permission that I place in the Manifest file, or do I need to code it so that a dialog box pops up asking for the permission to write to storage when the button is longpressed? Thanks.

Comment: you should change your reference path reference , and for permission you should ask in the manifest and also in the run time for android M and above

Comment: You Sir are a star! Thank you so much; it works and the file downloads to my Download directory. Do I have to use this method for each individual button and sound, or is there a way that I can easily apply the method for all of my buttons, so that they will download their respective sounds when pressed? Many thanks.

Comment: P.s. I have marked your answer as accepted and tried to up vote it (though I am new, so do not know if it counts). I thank you again for your help.

Comment: thanks, you can use for each button and sound just change the sound source in the param according to you button  , hope you can upvote it to make more relevant as answer for the others :) .

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to apply what you have posted, but I have probably gone wrong somewhere.

I have been trying to save the sound file to internal storage (as I don't have External Memory). When I long press on the button, the message I have put in pops up to say that the file has saved (so far to the directory of the app), but I don't think that it actually saves there at all.

Can you take a look at my code please and see where I have gone wrong. Thanks for helping this noob out, I do really appreciate people's help!

''''@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button a;

    a = findViewById(R.id.button11);

    a.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {

            String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

            try {
                copyRAWtoPhone(R.raw.nickingbentcoppers, path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Saved to " + getFilesDir(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
                               }

        private void copyRAWtoPhone(int nickingbentcoppers, String path) throws IOException {

            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(nickingbentcoppers);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }

        }
    }); ''''
```